# Error compile Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

My development environment: Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3, running on Windows 10 (x64). XCode 8.2.1 running on Mac El Capitan 10.11.5.

When building an iOS app in Delphi with a 32bit iOS target using 32 bit version of libReachability.a obtained from http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5, I get following compile time error:

**[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp (offset=0xFFFFCF2C) is too big in libReachability.a(Reachability.o)
  ld: warning: unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp (offset=0xFFFFCF6F) is too big in libReachability.a(Reachability.o)
  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
    Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue", referenced from:      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability stopNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
      Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
      Error: "_CNCopySupportedInterfaces", referenced from:      __ZN14Captivenetwork25CNCopySupportedInterfacesEv in C:\Temp\NetworkState\iOSDevice32\Debug\CaptiveNetwork.o; 
      Error: "_CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo", referenced from:      __ZN14Captivenetwork24CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfoEP10__CFString in C:\Temp\NetworkState\iOSDevice32\Debug\CaptiveNetwork.o; 
      Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
      Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability stopNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
      Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:      -[Reachability isReachable] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability isReachableViaWWAN] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability isReachableViaWiFi] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability connectionRequired] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability isConnectionOnDemand] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability isInterventionRequired] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       -[Reachability reachabilityFlags] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o);       ...
    Error: "_SCErrorString", referenced from:      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
      Error: "_SCError", referenced from:      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libReachability.a(Reachability.o); 
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7**

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: As per my reply in the comments in the article, I'll be looking into this, hopefully within the next couple of hours or so

Comment: I don't receive any errors, using Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 and Xcode 9.2. Are you building the demo project?

Comment: @DaveNottage Demo project is not working too... same error!  I will edit my question and add complete message error...

Comment: After delete iphone SDK on delphi and add again (SDK Manager - iOS Device 32 bits), error change to:
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\Heber\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS10.2.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
  ld: file not found: /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration